# Building binary with not default target 'all' in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have simple `Makefile` below. That runs clear when using default target `all`.

```
objects = foo.o bar.o all.o
all: $(objects)

all2: $(objects)

# These files compile via implicit rules
foo.o: foo.c
bar.o: bar.c
all.o: all.c

all.c:
    echo "int main() { return 0; }" > all.c
    
    
%.c:
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f *.c *.o all2
```

But when I execute `make all2` I got:

```
touch foo.c
cc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
touch bar.c
cc    -c -o bar.o bar.c
echo "int main() { return 0; }" > all.c
cc    -c -o all.o all.c
touch all2.c
cc    -c -o all2.o all2.c
cc   all2.o foo.o bar.o all.o   -o all2
rm all2.o all2.c
```

`all2` target depends on `foo.o bar.o all.o`, but why it trying to get `all2.c` ?

Why it executes `clean` target at he end? Line `rm all2.o all2.c`

Comment: Look up "phony targets": `.PHONY: all2`
It's an implicit rule, if you don't want something to produce a file. By default a target will create some implicit rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that make has a built-in rule that knows how to build a binary file from an object file that has the same prefix; that is, given a binary file `foo` make has a built-in rule that knows how to build it from `foo.o`.

You have a target `all2` and normally that doesn't matter because you don't have an `all2.c` and so make can't find a way to build `all2.o` and so it decides there's no rule to build `all2`.

But in your makefile, you've created a rule to build any `.c` file, so when make tries to find a way to build `all2.o` it discovers it can be built from `all2.c` and there is a rule to build `all2.c`, so the rule matches.

Of course, you won't have a rule like `%.c : ; touch $@` in your non-test makefile so you won't see this problem in any real makefile.

If you want to make this work for your test environment you can, as @Cheatah says, declare the `all2` rule to be phony which will prevent make from trying to look up any rules to build it.

Comment: And he doesn't see this problem for the normal `make all` because `all` and `all.c` are real files in his project.